# Merge xarray dataset tiles

Tags: xarray

I have 15 xarray datasets that represent tiles of big area in x,y dimension. Each dataset has 2-3 GB size with lat, lon and time coordinates.  I converted data types from `float64` to `float32` to decrease the size of the files into half. Time dimension of datasets may or may not match. I would like to merge all these data to make one dataset for further data processing. I used `merged = file1.combine_firsrt(file2)`, `merged = merged.combine_first(file3)` and so one, but this is taking really long hours and eventually my computer (RAM 16 GB, Win64) is running out of time after merging 5 tiles. Interestingly merged data size is much higher than the sum of the original tiles. I am new to python and feel like this is not an elegant way.

How do I effectively merge these datasets?

Comment: Have you tried [`xr.concat`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.concat.html)? Some more details [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/combining.html)

Comment: Thanks Jose, what would be a 'dim' in my case? I tried dim='x', dim='y', dim='time', but none resulted desired result.